# Access Child state value in Parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child

I have (e.g.) two components in React. First one `App.js` is a parent component. It pass some values to the child component `Child.js`. In `child.js,` it receives the values via `props` and update some `state` variables using `axios` call results. this works fine.

Now I need to get that updates result value in `App.js`. how to get that value in `App.js`?

App.js

```
this.state ({ ... 
    examResult: null // need to update this with the child component result.
 })

<ChildComponent 
    Id={this.state.StudentId} 
    Name={this.state.StudentName}
/>
```

Child.js

```
state {
   examResult: null
}
...
componentDidMount()
{
    const {Id, Name} = this.props;
    axios.get( .... //To get the Result
    this.setState(
    { examResult: examResult} //Update the result to state variable. It wors fine. I need to pass this value to App.js
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Parent:

```
updateResults(results) {
   this.setState({examResult:results});
}
render() {
   return (<ChildComponent 
    Id={this.state.StudentId} 
    Name={this.state.StudentName}
    updateResults={this.updateResults.bind(this)}
/>)
}
```

Child:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    const {Id, Name, updateResults} = this.props;
    axios.get( ....).then(results => //To get the Result
      updateResults(results.data)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass another function as props. And from child component you can call that function and pass whatever parameters you need in your parent component.

Ex:

```
<ChildComponent 
    Id={this.state.StudentId} 
    callback={this.callbackfn}
    Name={this.state.StudentName} />
```

Where this.callbackfn will be a function in your parent component.

From child component you can call it as

> this.props.callback

Comment: Sorry.. I dont get you. What is `<Parent>` here and from where I have to do call this?

Comment: So, in the child component, i can able to call the `this.props.callback`. If I set state inside this function, then I can access that same variable in `App.js` ? If I am wrong could you give any example

Comment: You can pass that variable as an argument to that callback function.